Does the reported attack on SPN have any near term consequences for wallet security?
It is reported that an attack on Substitution-Permutation Network (SPN) has been developed with the currently available quantum annealing system from D-wave, as reported in the mostly Chinese paper:

The Reg understands the research team, led by Wang Chao from Shanghai University, used a D-Wave machine to attack Substitution-Permutation Network (SPN) structured algorithms that perform a series of mathematical operations to encrypt info. SPN techniques are at the heart of the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) – one of the most widely used encryption standards.
The tech targeted in the attack include the Present and Rectangle algorithms, and the Gift-64 block cipher, and per the Post produced results that the authors presented as “the first time that a real quantum computer has posed a real and substantial threat to multiple full-scale SPN structured algorithms in use today.”

Is this a real world practical threat today, or in the near future?  Does not reusing addresses protect oneself from such an attack?
